# Perform a function randomly between 1 and 5 seconds in javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I'm wondering what the best way is to perform a function randomly between 1 and 5 seconds. I understand that I can use setInterval but this requires a set number to trigger it off. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: same interval each time, or different?  And what do you mean by "requires a set number to trigger it off" ?!

Comment: setTimeout and inside call it again with a random number

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout` with random timeout, and at the end of the function schedule it's next execution:

```
var schedule = function(){
   yourfunc();
   window.setTimeout(schedule, randnumber);
}
window.setTimeout(schedule, randnumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('triggered');
}, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) * 1000)
```